# Read multiple property file in build.xml

Tags: java, xml, selenium, ant, jenkins

My setup is of Selenium + Junit + Ant + Jenkins

Trying to get a perfect way to create multiple Jenkins job where each job is reading different property file using ant. I am thinking of creating multiple property.xml file in my project and all the property file is configured in build.xml.

I can create multiple target in build.xml but every target need different property file, how to initialize individual property file for individual target?
Please help me on this, so that I can build a standard integrated framework.

Answer (score 0):

In your **Invoke Ant** build step
- Click the **Advanced...** button after the Targets dropdown
- This will open up two more fields (Build File and Properties)
- Under **Properties**, enter your properties in the format:
`property_name=value`

This is same as passing `-Dproperty_name=value` on ant command line.